# WordPress dev in local, subdomain, or subfolder

Tags: wordpress

I have a website running on a Wordpress theme. We have made many custom edits of the theme which now breaks when we turn on mobile version. We need to setup a test environment of the site so we can debug it. Is it best to setup a copy of the site as a subdomain, subfolder or do it locally. What is best practice. Thanks.

Comment: it doesn't matter where you put it.. as long as you do it correctly..

Comment: Try asking on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Wow, didn't even know about a wordpress stackexchange. Awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be a local setup. But if you don't want to configure to much to test it on your mobile device, you should setup a second installation on your server and make it available via a subdomain. (And of course, if it's on a live server, create a password protection to make it unseen for public eyes.)